# SPFX Application customizer extension only run if i run it locally and will stop working when I deploy to the app catalog

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-extensions, applicationcustomizers

I want to inject some CSS to my SharePoint page, so I follow those steps to create SPFX Application customizer extension:-

```
md app-extension
cd app-extension
yo @microsoft/sharepoint

What is your solution name?: app-extension
Which baseline packages do you want to target for your component(s)? SharePoint Online only (latest)
Which type of client-side component to create?: Extension
What is your Application Customizer name? HelloWorld
What is your Application Customizer description? HelloWorld description
```

then i added the following code inside the `.ts`:-

```
import { override } from '@microsoft/decorators';
import { Log } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseApplicationCustomizer
} from '@microsoft/sp-application-base';
import { Dialog } from '@microsoft/sp-dialog';

import * as strings from 'HelloWorldApplicationCustomizerStrings';

const LOG_SOURCE: string = 'HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer';

/**
 * If your command set uses the ClientSideComponentProperties JSON input,
 * it will be deserialized into the BaseExtension.properties object.
 * You can define an interface to describe it.
 */
export interface IHelloWorldApplicationCustomizerProperties {
  // This is an example; replace with your own property
  cssurl: string;
  scripturl: string;
}

/** A Custom Action which can be run during execution of a Client Side Application */
export default class HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer
  extends BaseApplicationCustomizer<IHelloWorldApplicationCustomizerProperties> {

    @override

    public onInit(): Promise<void> {
      Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Initialized ${strings.Title}`);
  
      const cssUrl: string = this.properties.cssurl;
      const scriptUrl: string = this.properties.scripturl;

      const url = window.location.href;
      if (cssUrl && url.toLowerCase()=="https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/customeroperations/sitepages/dashboard.aspx") {
          // inject the style sheet
          const head: any = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
          let customStyle: HTMLLinkElement = document.createElement("link");
          customStyle.href = cssUrl;
          customStyle.rel = "stylesheet";
          customStyle.type = "text/css";

          const head2: any = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
          
          head.insertAdjacentElement("beforeEnd", customStyle);
          head2.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="300">');

          

      }
      
      return Promise.resolve();
    }
}
```

and the following inside the `elements.xml`:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction
        Title="HelloWorld"
        Location="ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer"
        ClientSideComponentId="e1b2d761-b43b-4006-8838-a4ba934e053f"
        ClientSideComponentProperties="{&quot;cssurl&quot;:&quot;/Style%20Library/custom.css&quot;}">
    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Now when I run `gulp serve` the extension worked well, where the .CSS file took effect >> but when I deploy the SPFX to the app catalogue >> and I added the app inside the site collection >> the SPFx will not load the custom CSS + my browser console will raise this error:-

[image]

so why the SPFx is requesting the `hello-world-application-customizer.js` from local host? and is this the reason why the SPFX is not loading the custom css?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to run the following commands to ensure things are bundled correctly for production:

```
gulp clean
gulp bundle --ship
gulp package-solution --ship
```

Now when you deploy to the App Catalog the confirmation dialog will no longer show Localhost but SharePoint Online.

[image]

Comment: yes this fixed the issue .. thanks .. so the documentation @ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/serving-your-extension-from-sharepoint is confusing

Comment: Glad to hear it! I agree, that could be clearer for sure. I'd recommend either submitting an edit to the docs or making a comment (will go directly into the issues list).